# How to read smart contract balances of particular adress

Tags: web3js, ethers.js

sorry if this is very googlable,but i coudnt manage to find good info so far.

I want to read balances of particular adresses on different smart contracts, and even better if i can get the value of staked tokens like crvAave for exmample. So,like a zapper clone, as i want to learn by doing this.

From the documentation at web3 and ethers.js i coudnt find how to look for it yet.

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: You would have to look at the documentation of the specific contract  you want to query (or even better, look at the contract directly), it should have a view function that returns that kind of info. Sushiswap masterchef for example calls it `userInfo()`

Comment: Or are you trying to get the balance of an address for a particular token? if yes you want to call the token contracts code `balanceOf()` function

Comment: Thanks Foxxxey! Im trying to get the balance depoosited of an adress in a smart contract. For example if i deposited in sushi ETH/USDC, i want  to get the staked tokens/value $ of my adress.
So to build a zapper type of clone, i would have to scan all the main contracts on ethereum and do the balanceOf( ) i guess?

Comment: If you deposited ETH/USDC LP tokens, your tokens are in masterchef. To retrieve your balance in that contract (at address 0xef0881ec094552b2e128cf945ef17a6752b4ec5d on ETH mainnet) you'd have to query its `userInfo` function. It take 2 parameters, an `address` (thats your wallet address) and a `pid` (thats the internal ID used by the contract to refer to the ETH/USDC pool, you can find it by looking at a transaction where you deposited/harvested/withdrew from this pool). It returns 2 numbers, the data you want to get is the 1st one, that will give you the number of LP tokens you have staked...

Comment: ... in wei, just divide by 1e18 to get the number of tokens. Now if you want to get the $ value of those that's trickier, you might want to look at how sushiswap implemented it on their frontend, im not sure myself.